# How can I create an Html file?

Tags: java, html, eclipse

So I have a project I just started it today and I'm an absolute beginner in programming. 
in this project you have to write the name of an HTML file to create it on your deskpot when You click on a button "add a file ". How can I do it please ?!

```
textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(28, 50, 219, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Ajouter Un Fichier");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        File file = new File (textField.getText());

        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    });
```

Comment: I downvote really reluctantly, but if you think that someone will do your tasks for you here - you are wrong! Show us at least what you have tried so far. If nothing is done, do some effort and give it a try. We re here to help, not to work for you

Comment: Could you post some code so we can see how far you've gotten already? Otherwise this question could be closed...

Comment: Lol i didn't say you work for me you have just to ask and I'll show it to you !

Comment: Great, you added code. Do you have a question about your code?

Comment: I dont know how to make it an HTML file

Comment: When i type the name of a file, the only thing that they create is an unknown file, it wont even open saying that there's no such a programme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create an HTML file you need to write some HTML content into the file. It would be more nice if you name the output file with the **.html** suffix.

So after you get the file name from that `JTextField`, you should add a **.html** suffix to it's name and then use that to create the File.

After that have to write some html tags as Strings using that `BufferedWriter bw` into the destination file. It creates it (if it does not exist) and writes the html tags into it:

```
String html = "<html> <head></head> <body></body> </html>";
bw.write(html);
bw.flush();
bw.close();
```

So you can add the above code under the following line:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
```

and inside the `try-catch` block.

Also typically you should close the streams in the `finally` block, so you should add a `finally` block under the `catch` block and close `bw` inside it. Also the `bw.close()` may `throw` a checked exception and you need to put a `try-catch` inside the `finally` block. Another good try is to use `try with resource` if you are using java 7 or above.

Good Luck.

Comment: I feel stupid i didnt add the .html at the end THANK YOUUUUUUUU

Comment: `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
   
  btnNewButton.setEnabled(false);                                                           
 File file = new File (textField.getText()+".html");`